# Custom file download in mvc difficulty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to work out the example from http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/10/writing-a-custom-file-download-action-result-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx, however, I am having the error message:

> Access to the path 'C:\Dev\myproject\zippedFile' is denied.

or can I have an example of file downloading in MVC

Help please.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET application pool identity (SYSTEM\NETWORK SERVICE by default) must have read access to the directory holding the file(s).

Comment: How should I do that? Is it a configuration?

Comment: Right click on the folder, properties, security, permissions

Comment: I don`t have security, permissions, rather, i have Genatal, Sharing - local sharing and security, network sharing and security/ web sharing, customize...

Comment: Then go to "local sharing and security"

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            file.SaveAs("file path goes here" + file.FileName);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

In your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

And like Mathieu says, make sure where ever you are storing the files, your worker process has access to it. Best bet is to store the files within the site `/Upload` for example.